# UIButton still calls IBAction after it's disabled

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, ibaction

I'm having a problem with the enabling/disabling of a UIButton, disabling the button works fine if I don't enable it again later in my code. When I do enable it later on it shows up as though it's disabled (the opacity changes) yet when I press it the attached IBAction function is still called.

The code:

```
- (void)loadDataFromURL:(NSURL *)URL withLoadIndicator:(UIActivityIndicatorView *)loadIndicator errorName:(NSString *)name sender:(id)sender andCallback:(SEL)selector{

    // Start loading indicator, block button so we will have only one call at a time
    [loadIndicator startAnimating];

    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton *button = sender;
        [button setEnabled:NO];
    }

    // Run the data load sequence
    self.dispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.companyname.settingsqueue", 0);

    dispatch_async(self.dispatchQueue, ^{
        // Downloading JSON and using CoreData to put it into the sqlite database here
    });

    // After loading is complete stop animating and re-enable the button
    dispatch_async(dispatchQueue, ^{
        [loadIndicator stopAnimating];
        if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            UIButton *button = sender;
            button.enabled = YES;
        }
    });
}
```

The strange thing is it works perfectly for the loadIndicator. The button I get from the sender parameter in the function does exist (it's not null). When I remove  `button.enabled = YES;` it stays disabled as it should. Is there a way to enable it again after my async code has executed without the button still being enabled during the async execution?

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem after extensive searching. Because I wasn't running all my UIView functions on the main thread the UI didn't update even though my function finished. Therefor the button disabled for a really short time and then enabled again, even though my overlaying UIView and UIActivityIndicator were not yet removed from the screen.

I hope this helps someone else with similar issues.